# transferFrom in contract function doesn't work

Tags: contract-development

I'm trying to make a simple `transferFrom` within my contract using remix.

Contract code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

// Import OpenZeppelin's ERC20 interface defenition
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.0.0/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.0.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.0.0/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";



// Simple ERC20 token that mints the given initialSupply to the deployer
contract MYTOKEN is ERC20  {
    constructor()  ERC20("mytoken", "MYTOKEN") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals())));
    }
    
   function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {

    }
}

contract SmartSub {
    using SafeERC20 for MYTOKEN;
    

    mapping(address => uint256) public bank;

    function deposit(uint amount) public {
        // The address is MYTOKEN address after i have deployed it
        MYTOKEN(0x0fC5025C764cE34df352757e82f7B5c4Df39A836).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        bank[msg.sender] += amount;
    }

}
```

beforehand i approve 10000 tokens, where i allow the contract address to transfer MYTOKEN from my account (the one i created all contracts with). After calling allowance with contract address i see the amount i have allowed before as expected.

Then i head to deposit function, where i input 10. After executing it, i see success but when i check the balance of my contract address i still see 0.

Why are the tokens not being transferred? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you override `transferFrom`? By doing so the original implementation is ignored and transferFrom does nothing.

If you want to do something extra and keep the implementation you can call the parent by using `super`.

```
function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {

    // Prepare things here

    bool result = super.transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount);

    // Do something here

    return result;
}
```

Comment: ahhh, indeed i shouldn't be doing that, thanks removing `transferFrom` from the erc20 completely, fixed my issue. I was fooled by errors that have happened before hand and i thought that i need to define `transferFrom` on the erc20 as if it was an interface.